# Creating class for missing variables in python

Tags: python, class, object-oriented-analysis

I would like to create class to find the missing values but below is my mistakes and how can I fix that please help?

```
     import pandas as pd
     data={'product':['A','B','C','D'],'sales':[100,None,256,100]}
     data=pd.DataFrame(data=data)

     class Information():
         def __init__(self):
            print('information object created')

         def get_missing_values(self):
            missing_values=data.isnull().sum()
            return missing_values

      class Ml:
            def __init__(self,data):
              print('DataPrep created') 
              self.data=data 
              self._info=Information()

     Ml=Ml(data)
    
    Ml.Information()
```

[image]

Comment: Well, `Ml` *doesn't* have an attribute `Information`; the code only defines the attributes `data` and `_info`. Why would you think it does otherwise?

Comment: are you sure Information should be a class and not a method of Ml?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
 import pandas as pd
 data = {'product':['A','B','C','D'],'sales':[100,None,256,100]}
 data = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

 class Information():
     def __init__(self, data):
         print('information object created')
         self.data = data
     def get_missing_values(self):
         missing_values = self.data.isnull().sum()
         return missing_values

 class Ml:
     def __init__(self,data):
         print('DataPrep created') 
         self.data = data 
         self.info = Information(data)

  ml = Ml(data)

  print(ml.info.get_missing_values())
```